# XML to string in velocity

Tags: html, xml, apache, templates, velocity

I have XML files that have nodes with formatted HTML. 
I am trying to print out the html contents to the page but velocity is stripping out the HTML tags.

How do you I print html content stored in an XML file using velocity?

#### XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<system-data-structure>
  <heading>This is a Title</heading>
  <main>
    <content>
      <h1>this is formatted html</h1>
      <p>content I want <b>to</b> <em>show</em> on my page
    </p>
    </content>
  </main>
</system-data-structure>
```

#### Velocity Code

```
#set ($html = $contentRoot.getChild('main').getChild('content'))
<h1>$contentRoot.getChild('heading').value</h1>
<div>$html.value</div>
```

*note: this is my first time ever using the velocity engine*

Answer (score 0):

Velocity doesn't strip anything out.  If you have the right event handlers configured you could have Velocity *escape* html output (which i don't think you want).  But there is no support in Velocity for stripping anything out.

What output are you actually getting?  Are you using a framework or CMS that is configuring Velocity for you?  Maybe it is something else that is "stripping out the html tags".

Comment: I am using velocity to format templates in Cascade Server CMS, which parses XML data into an object ($contentRoot). It turns out there is a $_SerializerTool object to parse the XML object back to a string. http://www.hannonhill.com/kb/Script-Formats/#serializer-tool